# Question about scan.ranges information

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to make sure I understand laser scan data.
`ranges` is an array of scan distances. so:

`ranges[0]` shows scan distance at `angle_min`.

`ranges[1]` shows scan distance at `angle_min+angle_increment`.

`ranges[2]` shows scan distance at `angle_min+(2*angle_increment)`
and so on? Is this correct

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409972/question-about-scan.ranges-information/) by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2022-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your understanding seems correct.

http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2022-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-12-01**:
@Martin Peris The values in the `ranges` array are the distances with reference to the sensor frame?

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2022-12-18**:
Sorry, I missed your comment. Yes, the values in ranges array are the distances with reference to the sensor frame (specified in the header of the message)